# Raise Textblock Tapped event manually

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, textblock

I have **TextBlock** I have declared it in **Xaml** with its **Tapped event**.Now i wanted to raise this event manually from code without actually Tap on it from external input.

```
 private void TxtBlkMessages_Tapped_1(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
  // want to raise it manually
  // some storyboards animation is present in it
 }
```

I have defined it in xaml like this..

```
<TextBlock Name="TxtBlkMessages"  Tapped="TxtBlkMessages_Tapped_1" />
```

More precisely i want to raise it from viewmodel on basis of some condition.

Comment: if codes inside the event handler don't use `sender` and `e` params : `TxtBlkMessages_Tapped_1(null, null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to raise manually then simply u can call the method

Example :

```
private void CallManually()
{    
    TxtBlkMessages_Tapped_1(null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call:

```
TxtBlkMessages.RaiseEvent(new TappedRoutedEventArgs());
```